# Error occurred while executing a write operation to database 'component' due to limited free space on the disk (1759 MB)

Tags: database, nexus3

I am getting database error while creating tasks in nexus repository management, in the logs it showing as follows.

### Error Log

```
2022-09-23 09:57:34,637+0000 ERROR [status-delayed-tasks-2-thread-1] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPooled - $ANSI{green {db=component}} Error on transaction commit `52E3D568`
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OLowDiskSpaceException: Error occurred while executing a write operation to database 'component' due to limited free space on the disk (1751 MB). The database is now working in read-only mode. Please close the database (or stop OrientDB), make room on your hard drive and then reopen the database. The minimal required space is 4096 MB. Required space is now set to 4096MB (you can change it by setting parameter storage.diskCache.diskFreeSpaceLimit) .
        DB name="component"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.checkLowDiskSpaceRequestsAndReadOnlyConditions(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:5073)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.commit(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1729)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:541)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:99)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2908)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2870)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.transaction.OrientTransaction.commit(OrientTransaction.java:74)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.TransactionalWrapper.proceedWithTransaction(TransactionalWrapper.java:69)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.Operations.proceedWithTransaction(Operations.java:232)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.Operations.transactional(Operations.java:223)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.Operations.run(Operations.java:175)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.transaction.OrientOperations.run(OrientOperations.java:62)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.internal.status.OrientStatusHealthCheckStore.checkWritable(OrientStatusHealthCheckStore.java:82)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.internal.status.OrientStatusHealthCheckStore$$EnhancerByGuice$$180293120.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:74)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$GuardImpl.run(StateGuard.java:272)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.GuardedInterceptor.invoke(GuardedInterceptor.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.invoke(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.internal.status.OrientStatusHealthCheckStore$$EnhancerByGuice$$180293120.checkWritable(<generated>)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.internal.freeze.OrientFreezeService.checkWritable(OrientFreezeService.java:119)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.thread.DatabaseStatusDelayedExecutor.lambda$1(DatabaseStatusDelayedExecutor.java:103)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.thread.DatabaseStatusDelayedExecutor.lambda$0(DatabaseStatusDelayedExecutor.java:90)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.thread.internal.MDCAwareRunnable.run(MDCAwareRunnable.java:40)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.doRun(SubjectRunnable.java:120)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.run(SubjectRunnable.java:108)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

so anyone knows what's the wrong with it or what may cause this problem?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue, I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus **needs at least 4096 MB Freespace available** to run properly,
thus it will be running (Read-Only) and you'll not be able to pull or push to the registry

So, just check the free space on the disk and if you're running nexus on Kubernetes check PVC size also if you're using NFS mount point check the free space available for this mount path and its disk also.