# Nexus: Unable to delete repository when database is frozen.. Database not writable on node

Tags: nexus, nexus3

i am trying to publish or to delete from nexus, i get this error:

> Unable to delete repository when database is frozen.. Database not
> writable on node

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give more information about your problem but I posted this answer for common situations.

Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73825953/error-occurred-while-executing-a-write-operation-to-database-component-due-to):

> The Nexus needs at least 4096 MB free space available to run properly,
> thus it will be running (Read-Only) and you'll not be able to pull or
> push to the registry

At first you should check the log file of Nexus to get the exact error:
It's located in the following directory if you installed it in `/opt`

> /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/nexus.log

Change it based on your installed directory.

### **In my case the problem was due to limited free space on the disk (less than 4G)** so I got the error because **it was running in read-only mode**. I extend the disk space and the problem was solved.